# Handling Tab and Alt+* keys in modeless dialogs hosted by modal dialog

Tags: windows, dialog, keystroke, modeless

We have a set of modeless dialogs that are children of a modal dialog. Only one of the modeless dialogs appears at a time; the others are hidden. This is controlled by elements in the modal dialog. If you think of a Windows property sheet you'll have the idea.

It all works fine except for the Tab key and the Alt+char hotkeys. They don't do what they're supposed to do, i.e., navigate the controls in the active modeless dialog. They just beep.

In a normal scenario, i.e., a modeless dialog owned by the application window, this is handled by calling IsDialogMessage() in the application's message loop. We can't do that because it's not our message loop--Windows is running the message loop to service the modal dialog, and all we get are messages sent to the dialog proc.

We're trying to think of ways to handle this without having to resort to doing all of the navigation ourselves via WM_GETDLGCODE.

Any ideas? Straight C++ Win32 API, none of that newfangled stuff the kids are all using these days.

TIA

ADDITIONAL INFO: Further investigation reveals that Windows is applying the navigation keys to the host modal dialog, not to the child modeless dialogs. We need them to go to the modeless dialogs.

Answer (score 1):

The answer, found by a colleague, turns out to be adding the DS_CONTROL style to the modeless dialogs.

Raymond Chen discusses DS_CONTROL [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/30/201988.aspx).

It's amazing that you can work with Windows every day for 20 years and still run across stuff that you've absolutely never heard of.

Comment: Here's a fixed link to Raymond Chen discusses DS_CONTROL: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040730-00/?p=38293